# Received close_notify during handshake SSL Error?

Tags: java, security, ssl, java-8, tls1.2

We have been facing this weird error in productions where on high volumes (~10 thousand per hour), 10% of our calls are getting rejected with SSL exception mentioned below. This has been happening since a java 8 minor version update.(JDK-8028518 ).

```
Received close_notify during handshake
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Received close_notify during handshake
                at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:129)
                at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
                at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
```

As this is only failing for a percentage of the calls, we are not able to understand why this might be happening.

We use the below line to set the ssl context in the client side code

```
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance(TLS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case this was happening because the handshake was taking too long.
This was because on the client side, before making the call, our reads from the secure store were taking too long causing the handshake to fail midway half the time. This was prevented by introducing caching of the secure store related objects to not instantiate them again and again.

Answer (score 2):

`javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Received close_notify during handshake`

Can you check your server thread count configuration?

One possibility could be under high load, more(relatively) high latency requests causing this issue.

Under light load, there might be enough threads on the server to handle all the traffic(as high latency requests will also be relatively less)

One possible option is to

1. increase the actual application servers under your load balancer
2. reduce the number of threads configured on each application based on the throughput of the system.